# How to convert Shapefile to KML in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, kml, pyproj

My goal is to extract certain shapes from a shapefile, and render the chosen shapes in a KML file. From searching gis.stackexchange, I was able to piece together the necessary components, and the answer I came to seems to be very close. However, a shape in Gilbert, Arizona is rendered in Kogi, Nigeria. Are the ArcGIS point coordinates relative to a specific reference point?

For the shape files themselves, you can see my project at https://github.com/pmains/geo_shapes

```
    from pyproj import Proj, transform
    import shapefile
    import simplekml

    def esri_to_geo(*points):
        # ArcGIS format
        in_proj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
        # Standard geodetic format
        out_proj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
        # New array that will hold points in latitude/longitude
        new_points = []
        for point in points:
            x2, y2 = transform(in_proj, out_proj, point[0], point[1])
            # Append points as tuples
            new_points.append((x2, y2))
        return new_points

    def main():
        # Read in all precincts
        sf = shapefile.Reader("VotingPrecincts.shp")
        shape_records = sf.shapeRecords()

        # Find Gilbert Gardens (Precinct 251)
        for i in xrange(len(shape_records)):
            sr = shape_records[i]
            if 'GILBERT GARDENS' in sr.record:
                break

        # Create KML file
        kml = simplekml.Kml()
        kml.newpolygon()
        poly = kml.features[0]
        # Convert points
        pts = esri_to_geo(*sr.shape.points)
        poly.outerboundaryis = pts
        kml.save("GilbertGardens.kml")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: I am no expert in python, so I will put different logic: did you first try to convert shapefiles and see are they rendering in wanted region? or maybe create two scripts for specific goal you are trying to accomplish to see where is your mistake. also, your file from git hub are working fine for me, they are rendered in arizona. i just opened new blank map, imported your shapefiles, and added basemap to check, and it is working fine

Comment: When you say you opened a new blank map, did you import the KML file into Google's My Maps? Did your KML file look like the GilbertGardens.kml file in the repo?

Comment: I meant it for the voting precints shapefile. Sadly, your kml is also rendering in Nigeria. I think there are some problems with projection/reprojection. I would first reproject your files, manually to see. your projection is "NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Arizona_Central_FIPS_0202_Feet_Intl
WKID: 2868 Authority: EPSG", and kml form google are in wgs84. (GCS_WGS_1984
WKID: 4326 Authority: EPSG), i think you should convert it between those two

Comment: That did get me closer. I hadn't looked at the project (.prj) file previously. Now, my map has moved from Nigeria to Colorado.

Comment: Close, but still not good. First, I would reproject data, from "NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Arizona_Central_FIPS_0202_Feet_Intl" to "WGS84", (from 2868 to 4326). and of course, be careful about geographic transformations. when you get the right transformation, you can integrate it in your code.